# CSS horizontal menu with resizing images in the correct aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I can't find a solution to this, although I'm sure it's simple!

I've created a horizontal menu using an unordered list and a series of images i.e for 'home', 'about' etc.  Each of the images vary in width but have the same height of 25px.

When I resize the browser I want the menu to shrink in width and in height.

The current code is as follows:

```
<style>

#container ul.content_list {
}
#container ul.content_list li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
#container ul.content_list li .image{
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 25px;
}
#container ul.content_list li .image img {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%; /* comment this out to make the images the correct width and height */
    max-height: 25px;
}

</style>

<div id="container">
    <ul class="content_list">
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="homeOff.png" />
                <img src="aboutOff.png" />
                <img src="servicesOff.png" />
                <img src="portfolioOff.png" />
                <img src="contactOff.png" />
                <img src="blogOff.png" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've put together a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/CAM79/JQuuj/

Currently the menu is shrinking in width and height but the heights of the images are wrong.

Commenting out the 'width: 15%' (highlighted in the code) will display the images correctly but then they wrap rather than skrink.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your design responsive, you have to think that it will react to the width of the screen while the user is resizing it. Then it would be much more easier to make all your images with the same width. According to your design it's possible BUT I would not recommand using pictures in a menu!!! If you look at the css gradients you can achieve the same design you have now without using any pic (which is much better for SEO). To conclude, check how to use ul and li tags properly, you can also delete all your classes and just target with tag names which will make your code lighter. You should end with something like that:

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li><a>Home/</a></li>
    <li><a>About/</a></li>
    <li><a>Services/</a></li>
    <li><a>portoflio/</a></li>
    <li><a>contact/</a></li>
    <li><a>blog/</a></li>
</ul>
```

and your css could for example have something like that:

```
#container ul li{
float: left;
width:15%;
background:black;
background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

}

#container ul li a{
color:yellow;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marion,

Many thanks for your contribution.  You have raised a valid point which I may use in the future.

Currently, I want to use the font which is in the graphics and therefore on this occasion I'm trying to fix the problem.